# Font size differences between VB6 and VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, vb6, fonts

When setting a point 10 font size in VB6:

```
Me.FontName = "Verdana"
Me.FontSize = 10
Debug.Print Me.FontSize
```

The reported font size is 9.75. However, when the same is done in VB.NET:

```
Me.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Verdana", 10)
Console.WriteLine(Me.Font.Size)
```

The reported size is 10. Can someone explain the difference here? My hunch is that VB6 is using a .75 step because my system is configured at 96 DPI, and .NET is not using said step, or not reporting its usage, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Note that when you set the font size to 10 pt in Visual Studio, then you'll also end up with 9.75.

Comment: have you tried other values as well?

Comment: Yes, they all seem to display the same behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong and both are techinically the same in display.  It just reporting the font "more accurately".  The font step size for 96dpi is 0.75 (0.6 at 120 DPI), so the steps are technically 9 to 9.75 to 10.5.

Comment: So VB6 is accurately displaying the font, whereas VB.NET is simply displaying what I requested?

Comment: Fonts sizes are "conceptual".  They are broken down into the various pt levels (9, 10, 10.5, 11, 12, 14) we've come to accept as standard representations.

Answer (score 0):

The step of Size property is `72 / GetDeviceCaps(hDC, LOGPIXELSY)` which in small-fonts (96 DPI) is 0.75 and in large-fonts (120 DPI) is 0.6

You can use [SetRatio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms691214(VS.85).aspx) on OleFont to control the denominator in the previous expression. `GetDeviceCaps` is the default setting.